# Interactive presentation / E-Learing software

Tags: open-source, presentation, flash, powerpoint

I have a client that has a interactive presentation that was created in Flash, He want's to update the presentation but because it has so many frames in it now it has become a bit of a monstrosity and hard to update things like adding new frames and being able to easily rearrange frames so we are looking to redo it.

We want the ease of updates and rearranging that can be found in presentation packages like PowerPoint. The topics and lesson setup where you have a menu where you can jump between any topic and page with each that you often find in E-Learning Authoring Software. The current presentation is quite animation heavy, currently using AS2 for things like snow fall, motion tweens for more complex (curves) motion paths etc.

Is there a software that can incorporate these things? And ideally not along the current trend of monthly subscription software.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Have you looked at SoftChalk Cloud?  Really cheap for us as a .edu and integrates to our LMS as an LTI so comprehension quizzes, etc can be put in the gradebook

Answer (score 1):

I you'd like an open source alternative to PowerPoint / Office:

> LibreOffice is a powerful office suite – its clean interface and feature-rich tools help you unleash your creativity and enhance your productivity.
>   LibreOffice includes several applications that make it the most powerful Free and Open Source office suite on the market.

**LibreOffice Impress**

> In Impress, creating and editing slides is very versatile thanks to different editing and view modes: Normal (for general editing), Outline (for organizing and outlining your text content), Notes (for viewing and editing the notes attached to a slide), Handout (for producing paper-based material), and Slide Sorter (for a thumbnail sheet view that lets you quickly locate and order your slides).

[LibreOffice Homepage](https://www.libreoffice.org)

*Note: LibreOffice is a fork of OpenOffice before OpenOffice was passed on to the Apache foundation. They both still exist. more info about [the difference between LibreOffice and OpenOffice](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=73389)*